# Visual Studio overriding URL set in appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I am currently working on an .Net Core WebAPI Project (netcore 2.0) and I want to define the URL my application runs on in my appsettings.json file. I then use the following code in my Program.cs file:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var url = config.GetSection("WebAppSettings").GetValue<string>("Url");

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseUrls(url)
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
{
    configBuilder
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
})
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
})
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseNLog()
.Build();

host.Run();
```

My appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "WebAppSettings": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:5023"
  }
}
```

However, when I run my application, it is only accessible on port 5022 (I previously set it to this but changed it to 5023 afterwards). When I look into my project properties and go to the "Debug" submenu, it states 5022 as the port. I tried erasing this property but it's an required field.

So how can I force Visual Studio to use the port I set in my appsettings.json file without it screwing up my settings?

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express uses `launchSettings.json`, which itself is set via the project properties settings you mentioned. `UseUrls` only applies outside of Visual Studio/IIS Express.

Comment: I guess there is no way to circumvent this? So that IIS Express will be fored to use whatever URL I supply via UseUrls?